# FlutterErrorDetail return null on release mode

Tags: flutter, error-handling

I'm using this code to catch errors in my flutter application and it works perfectly in debug mode but in release mode FlutterErrorDetails is null and I cant see what caused the error.

**how can I fix this?**

This is the code that I use:

```
  runZonedGuarded(() {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
   
    FlutterError.onError = (FlutterErrorDetails details) {
      if(MyApp.bugSentTime.isBefore(DateTime.now().add(Duration(seconds: -10)))){
        MyApp.sendBug(details);
        MyApp.bugSentTime = DateTime.now();
      }
    };

    runApp(MyApp());
  }, (error, stackTrace) {
    if(MyApp.bugSentTime.isBefore(DateTime.now().add(Duration(seconds: -10)))){
      FlutterErrorDetails details = FlutterErrorDetails(exception: error, stack: stackTrace);
      MyApp.sendBug(details);
      MyApp.bugSentTime = DateTime.now();
    }
    FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordError(error, stackTrace);
  });
```

And these are my results, first one is from release and the second one from debug mode

```
Wed Dec 30 2020 17:00:40 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) {
       mode: 'release',
       os: 'android',
       model: 'SM-N770F',
       brand: 'samsung',
       osVersion: '29',
       buildNumber: '1',
       buildVersion: '1.0.0',
       username: 'Emad',
       error: ''
}

Tue Dec 29 2020 01:47:40 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) {
       mode: 'debug',
       os: 'android',
       model: 'SM-N770F',
       brand: 'samsung',
       osVersion: '29',
       buildNumber: '1',
       buildVersion: '1.0.0',
       username: 'Emad',
       error: '══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE ╞═════════════════\n' +
         'The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:\n' +
         'Unable to load asset: assets/images/1.png\n' +
         'When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:\n' +
         .....
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably `FlutterErrorDetails` is not actually null, and you can get the info you want using other properties of the `details` object.

I had a similar experience. I found that the `FlutterErrorDetails` was **not** null. It was `details.toString()` that was the problem. It behaves differently in release mode and defaults to blank output.  *(sigh)*

(I bet your `sendBug(details)` uses `.toString()` explicitly or implicitly.)

In my case, the `detail.exception` and `details.stack` properties were available and populated. I was able to get good error logging in release mode by using them.

Comment: Thank you sir saved me lots of effort as it was in their documents to use toString I never thought of it.

Comment: Thanks a lot also from my side! But why would they set it up like this!